# split a column's value into 2 different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `T1` which has a column `A1`. The column has values like `James Patterson%Michael Ledwidge`

i need the value in these columns to be split into 2 other columns

A1= James patterson
A2= Michael Ledwidge

Likewise, there are 20 records in the table `T1`.

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you want to do this split for display purposes, or are you looking to make a permanent change to the data stored in the database?

Comment: If the two columns are going to store data of the same type (e.g. both are identifying authors), you ought to move these out to a separate table, with one row for each value, and Foreign Key back to the single row in your existing table. This avoids complicating searches (where with your design, you'd have to search A1 and A2 now), and allows the addition of an infinite number of `An` values in the future, not just two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say, two *other* columns, but one of them appears to be the same, `A1`.

Anyway:

```
UPDATE T1
SET
  A1 = SUBSTRING(A1, 1, CHARINDEX('%', A1) - 1),
  A2 = STUFF(A1, 1, CHARINDEX('%', A1), '')
WHERE CHARINDEX('%', A1) > 0
```